# mock restTemplate.exchange() method throwing MissingMethodExceptionin in groovy spock test

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock, spring-boot-test

Actual java code

```java
metadataContentList.addAll((restTemplate.exchange(SERVICE_URL + queryForIds, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, DocMetadataResponse.class, map).getBody()).getResults());
```

Here is a mock rest call

```
_ * mockRestTemplate.exchange(_ as String, _, _, DocMetadataResponse.class, _) >> { args ->
    def ids = (args[0] as String).split("\\?")[1].split("&").collect {
        it.split("=")[1]
    }
    new DocMetadataResponse(ids.size(), metadataContentList.findAll { args[2][0] == it.contextId })
}
```

Its throwing exception as

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.springframework.http.HttpEntity.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (Integer) 
values: [0]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), getBody(), grep(), tap(groovy.lang.Closure)
at com.mrll.javelin.drmaudit.service.DrmAuditServiceIntSpec.$spock_feature_0_1_closure12$_closure22
```

This was working fine with but with the new requirement i had to use `restTemplate.exchange()` method as I had to pass some header parameter

```
_ * mockRestTemplate.getForObject(_ as String, DocMetadataResponse.class, _)
```

I am new with Groovy so not able to understand why its throwing error for `exchange` method?

I tried stubbing mock `ResponseEntity` and `getBody` from it but then I get `NullPointerException`

All other mock restcall are working with `getForObject` and `postForObject` but failing with `exchange()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining about `args[2][0]`.

`args[2]` is the supplied `httpEntity` of type `org.springframework.http.HttpEntity`.

`args[2][0]` is Groovy syntactic sugar for calling `args[2].getAt(0)`.

And the error is telling you that there is no method `HttpEntity#getAt` that takes an `int` as argument, only one that is taking a `String` as parameter.

Comment: Is there any way we can fix this? i tried using Mock(HttpEntity) in the restcall but no luck

Comment: Sure, use a method that exists. I have no idea what you expect `[0]` to get you.